# sprite kit do not draw line at correct position in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

sprite kit do not draw line at correct position in portrait mode

sprite kit do not draw line at correct position in portrait mode. I try to draw line in sprite kit. before today sprite kit was working correctly but now only when app is in portrait mode it draw x position wrong . I try to draw x position = -750/4 but it draws x something like -750/2 + 750/20. y position of line is not correct also. how to make it work correctly?

```
extension GameScene{
func setScreenSize(width inputWidth:Double,height inputHeight:Double)
{
      let coordinatesX = 
Double(self.frame.size.width) 
// coordinatesX = 750
      let coordinatesY = Double(self.frame.size.height) 
// coordinatesY =  1334.0
}



func drawShapeNode()
    {
    theX  = CGFloat(-750/4)
    theY  = CGFloat(-1334.0/4)
    thePathToDraw.move(to: CGPoint(x: theX, y: theY))
    thePathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
}
```

Comment: You know that coordinate (0,0) is in the centre of the screen, yes? So that your x cordinates will run from -325 to 325 and the y coordinate from -667 to 667.

Comment: @SteveIves, only when anchorPoint is set to (0.5,0.5).  Apple keeps going back and forth on what the default anchorPoint value is,  in some versions of XCode it was (0,0), while others it is (0.5,0.5), so the OP may not be aware of what is anchor point value is

Comment: OP, I would recommend finding some tutorials to learn how `scaleMode` and scene size works, as well as learning about `anchorPoints`. What you think is center, may not actually be center, depending on how cropping is done.

Comment: @userForStackExchange - yes, check the scene’s anchor point first in the .sks file via scene builder. If you’re not sure, put a sprite at (0, 0) to see where that appears on your screen.

Comment: Steve Ives  , Knight0fDragon thanks I will do that later. actually point 0,0 is in the center and displays normally. other point have wrong position today.  also I have to say that game view is inside of scroll view.

Comment: anchorPoint is (0.5,0.5)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this wrong position occurs only when game view size width < screen width. this is why I noticed that only today and it was normal before. so making game view size width >= screen width fix it. this error is not related to scroll view so it occurs when view is not inside of scroll view.

Comment: you shouldnt be playing with game view size and screen size.  Everything should be using the scene size unless you are dealing with something outside the realm of sprite kit